# windows10の環境で、dokerのイメージを正しくビルドできているのか教えてください。

Tags: docker, windows-10

Dockerのイメージをビルドした際、表示の中で、下記エラーが発生しています。
正しくビルドできているのでしょうか？できていないようでしたら、処置方法についてご教示願います。

```
> docker build -t book-mlearn-image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon    170MB
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
fe703b657a32: Pull complete
f9df1fafd224: Pull complete
a645a4b887f9: Pull complete
・
・
Get:434 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 libtbb-dev amd64 4.4~20151115-0ubuntu3 [226 kB]
**debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed**
Fetched 238 MB in 16min 30s (240 kB/s)
・
・
Successfully built sklearn tornado absl-py pyyaml backcall prometheus-client pandocfilters html5lib pyrsistent
**ERROR: markdown 3.2.1 has requirement setuptools>=36, but you'll have setuptools 20.7.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 3.1.1 which is incompatible.**
Installing collected packages: idna, certifi, urllib3, chardet, requests, Pillow, nose, six, numpy, h5py, parso, jedi, 
・
・
Successfully built 2a07b70073f6
Successfully tagged book-mlearn-image:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\book-mlearn-gyomu-master\src>
```

Comment: 「すぐに使える！業務で実践できる！Pythonによる AI・機械学習・深層学習アプリのつくり方」という書籍の[こちら](https://github.com/kujirahand/book-mlearn-gyomu/blob/master/src/Dockerfile)のDockerfileでしょうか

Comment: そうです。書籍に沿って行っているつもりですがうまくいっているのかよく分かりません。